# tsql using like with wildcard and trailing space?

Tags: t-sql, wildcard, space, sql-like

I cannot get the like statement to work with space and trailing wildcard.
My query goes as follows:

`select * from Table where Field like 'Desc_%'`

The data is space-delimited such as, Desc Top, Desc Bottom and so on. The query works when I use the pattern 'Desc_%' but not when I use the pattern 'Desc %'. The field is nvarchar(255).

Any ideas?

EDIT

Turns out the data was tab-delimited and when I copied a value from the 2008 Management Studio it converted the tab to space. Dumb mistake. I did like the [ ] tip so I marked it the answer. Thanks everyone, I'll remember not to trust the copy from the grid results.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why "like 'Desc%'" won't work?

Comment: @AllenG - "LIKE Desc%" won't limit itself to "Desc " (D-e-s-c-blank), it'll pick up anything that starts with "Desc"

Comment: @DaveE - yes, it will, but if the only things that could be in his column are 'Desc Top', 'Desc Bottom', 'Desc InsideOut', etc, and never 'Descendant of Charlemaine', there's not a practical block to using Like Desc%.  If his table does contain those other values, of course, then he'd have a problem.

Comment: Belt and suspenders. Apparently his data isn't what he's expecting. FIND 'Desc %' *does* work for me on SS2005.

Comment: @DaveE you are right, there was a tab... ugh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use brackets '[' & ']' to set up a single-character class to match.  In your case the SQL should look like this: "select * from Table where Field like 'Desc[ ]%'"

EDIT: add sample, link

```
CREATE TABLE #findtest (mytext  varchar(200) )

insert #findtest VALUES ('Desc r')
insert #findtest VALUES ('Descr')

select * from #findtest where mytext like 'Desc[ ]%'

DROP TABLE #findtest

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
mytext
--------
Desc r

(1 row(s) affected)
```

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx/) article.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This works. I'm sorry for wasting you guys time. The data had a tab not a space. I copied the value from Management Studio grid and it converted the tab to a space.

Answer (score 0):

Since an underscore is a single character wildcard, and percent is the multi-char wildcard, they are the same ( "%" and "_%" ).  It is as if you are asking for two consecutive wildcards.  Not sure if I understand your question, but I am not surprised it does not behave the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Consider explicitly stating that you want a space, using its ASCII value?

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Field Like 'Desc' + CHAR(32) + '%'
```